# Problems with dpkg -i and brackets on 15.04

Tags: dpkg, 15.04

I downloaded the **deb** file from `http://brackets.io/` and ran

`sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/Brackets*`

and getting following error:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of brackets:
brackets depends on libgcrypt11 (>= 1.4.5); however:
Package libgcrypt11 is not installed.
```

This occurred after fresh install.

Answer (score 1):

`libgcrypt11` is a requirement for that package.  Unfortunately it doesn't exist in Vivid and was dropped.  It was replaced by a more updated libgcrypt - `libgcrypt20`.

Inform the upstream where you got the .deb from that they should test against `libgcrypt20` and if it still works they need to specify that as the dependency instead of `libgcrypt11`.  If it won't work with that newer package then the software won't work at all.

Ultimately the people producing the .deb have to fix this - there's nothing you can really do to fix this yourself.

Comment: small question, couldn't the user still get this from the ubuntu repositories for older releases ?

Comment: @serg they could however dependencies would likely break.  The issue is software which relies on older libraries, not a case of 'They can't install older libraries" (although this does become the issue eventually)

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here with an older version of Atom, install an older version of the library from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic-updates/libgcrypt11) and it works and there are no conflicts.

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/<your_library>
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/Brackets*
```

If the dependence is corrected later, then you can remove this library with:

```
sudo apt-get remove libgcrypt11
```

Comment: @EricNutter Were you satisfied with my answer? If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers ;)